# EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI cause IllegalStateException when using default bean name

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, wildfly, remote-access

I am following the prescribed method described in wildfly documentation [EJB invocations from a remote client using JNDI](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/EJB+invocations+from+a+remote+client+using+JNDI) to invoke a method on a stateless session bean from a remote client.  I am using wildfly 8.2.1 Final with NetBeans 8.0.2 in a maven project packaged in an ear and deployed via the IDE.  Using the jboss specific ejb: namespace to look up the bean using jndi name `ejb:<app-name>/<module-name>/<distinct-name>/<bean-name>!<fully-qualified-classname-of-the-remote-interface>` results in an IllegalStateException: No EJB receiver available for handling...  The problem arises when using the default bean-name described as

> bean-name : This is the name of the bean for which you are doing the
>   lookup. The bean name is typically the unqualified classname of the
>   bean implementation class, but can be overriden through either
>   ejb-jar.xml or via annotations. The bean name part cannot be an empty
>   string in the JNDI name.

Using the wildfly admin console, the bean is not present in the java:jboss/exported namespace, but is present in java:global.  Unless I specifically declare a bean name in the @Stateless annotation `@Stateless(name = "xyz")` and perform the lookup with this name, the remote invocation fails.  Explicitly declaring a bean name causes the bean to show up in the java:jboss/exported namespace of the JNDI tree.

Does anyone know why the default bean name (ie unqualified class name) does not work as documented?

Comment: Are you placing your `@Remote` annotation on the bean or on its remote interface?

Comment: @Remote(interface.class) is on the bean.  The remote interface is explicitly declared.